# Exclude several pages from wp_page_list

Tags: php, wordpress

Hye guys. I have wordpress template.php with listing custom  pages. I need to exclude from my listing 2 pages. Is it possible? I'll give what I have maybe somebody knows an answer. Will be happy to solve this problem . THANKS!

**WHAT I HAVE**

```
   <?php /* Template Name: # photography all archive */  get_header('photography'); ?>

<div class="base-content">

   <div id="archive-thumbnails-listing" >
    <?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 379,403)); ?>

     <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <div class="thumb12">
        <div class="thumb20"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a></div>
    <div class="thumb19"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

     </div>

</div>


<?php
$args = array(
   'exclude' => array(403), // exclude posts 379 and 403,

);

$pages = get_pages( $args ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that you can exclude pages using `get_pages`

The first is `exclude` where you can provide an array or an integer of the post ID(s).

The second is `exclude_tree` where you can provide the ID of a post and it will exclude any children of that post.

EX:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'exclude' => array(379,403), // exclude posts 379 and 403,
    'exclude_tree' => 379 // exclude any child of post 379
);

$pages = get_pages( $args );
```

Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: THANKS, but I still cant figuge out where to add this lines ( I'll update my question which all page template to see where I added this lines and its not working . i think I did something wrong^^